# Property Binding to Static Properties in WPF: Width binding doesn't work

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, binding

***Update: I've corrected the post, so the question is closed.***

**Expected result:** 
Menu width must be equal to the main window width.
Here is full code:

```
<Menu Name="menu1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
   <Menu.Width>
      <Binding Path="MainWindow.Width" 
               Source="{x:Static Application.Current}"
               UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
   </Menu.Width>
   <MenuItem Header="File">
       <MenuItem Header="Open" />
       <MenuItem Header="Close" />
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

**The result:** 
Menu width is equal to content width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh,

Dmitry, Application.Current doesn't have a property Width...

Use Grid instead of DockPanel:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Grid>
      <Menu Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
         <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close"/>
         </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

Don't overcomplicate things. And I really encourage you to read wonderful Dr. WPF articles: [ItemsControl from A to Z](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/)

Cheers, Anvaka

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it should be:

<Menu.Width>
    <Binding Path="MainWindow.Width" Source="{x:Static Application.Current}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
</Menu.Width>

Thanks for reference.